# Freelancer API snowtigerlib Wrapper Class for PHP didn't work

Tags: php, freelancer.com-api

I used snowtigerlib freelancer api, it is a php wrapper class. I downloaded the full code from this [link](http://code.google.com/p/snowtigerlib/download/list)

Then I setup `SnowTigerLib_Config.inc` file with my key and secret. Then I did the following step:

1. First it went to the following [url](http://www.sandbox.freelancer.com/users/api-token/auth.php?oauth_token=7740e3104f545e168d8880d850e333c95ff2b37b).
   Then I logged in to sandbox with my username and password.
2. Next step, it went the following [url](https://www.sandbox.freelancer.com/users/api-token/auth.php?oauth_token=47b9d304df6f67dc59430016f3f0038cb3e1213f).
   Here Authenticate API Access was authorized.
3. After Authorizing API access it went the following [url](https://www.sandbox.freelancer.com//users/api-token/onauth.php)

Here it shows that it is authorized and the automatically redirect into my callback url with following error:

**ERROR**

```
Notice: Undefined index: token in ..........\callback.php on line 4
HTTP Error: http_code:401 in ...............\SnowTigerLib.php on line 455
Details: http://api.sandbox.freelancer.com/RequestAccessToken/requestAccessToken.xml?oauth_consumer_key=7484ba1fdfa9138ec77ead0c881966ad43f194ba&oauth_nonce=5a9b4e19b1fcd551e416d8e1fa86ab50&oauth_signature=LKRcVWNRdE%2BIzAzem2svR%2F0OiG8%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1356949656&oauth_verifier=4a24c84d5b49465a51ca990e2114945894896ed6&oauth_version=1.0
```

Please give me reply if anybody knows this issue.

Comment: 401 means that it is missing authentication, and the reason is probably indicated by the notice you are getting - the `token` index is missing. Perhaps you need to supply the token in step 3?

Comment: @Arpit, FWIW I thought the original question was more readable `:)`. Quote blocks are good for error messages and URIs as they negate the need for horiz scrolling.